# Why does something thrown out of a train goes in the opposite direction?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, kinematics

As someone throws some thing out of the train in y direction it should move forward (in the direction of the train) in x direction, (wrt ground) as it has velocity component in the direction of moving train, But when observed in real situation it is opposite!

Comment: Air resistance reduces the component of velocity in the direction of motion. Making it seem to go backwards

Comment: I fear your claim of observational behavior is incorrect for many situations.

Answer (score 1):

Because of air resistance, if you throw something straight up in a 60 kilometer per hour wind it is blown away by the wind. The same thing happens when you throw something from a train going 60 kilometers per hour relative to the air around it.

Answer (score 1):

At the instant you throw the object out of the train its velocity relative to the ground is the same as that of the train.
Due to air resistance the velocity of the object, $v_{\rm object}$, will decrease relative to the ground whilst the velocity of the train, $v_{\rm train}$, stays the same, ie $v_{\rm object} < v_{\rm train}$.

The velocity of the object relative to the train is $v_{\rm object} - v_{\rm train}$ which is a negative quantity so an observer on the train sees the object travelling in the opposite direction to the train.